# Check if email address contains one of many domains from a table, ignoring the subdomain

Tags: ruby, email

I'm trying to validate email addresses as being from certain universities. I have a table, `University`, which is full of university domains. University email addresses often have different subdomains, and I want to be able to tolerate any subdomain under the domains in my table.

I think the following works, but is poorly written.  Can anyone suggest ways of refactoring this, with explanations?

```
domain = self.email.split("@")[1]

domain_test = false

University.all.each do |d|
  if domain.include?(d.domain)
    domain_test = true
    break
  end
end

if domain_test = false
  errors.add(:email, "Sorry, no match found")
end
```

Comment: how many universities are there?  a dozend? hundreds? thousands?

Comment: under a hundred!

Comment: your algorithm will allow the e-mail adress "hacker@mit.edu.ru" if "mit.edu" is in your list of domains.

Comment: ok, my code is bad in two ways. any chance you can suggest a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your current code first, I noticed the following:

- You should use `email.split('@').last` instead of an opaque numeric index (plus, you'll *always* get a string this way, whereas using `[1]` will return `nil` if the address doesn't contain an "@" to begin with)
- You should probably downcase the address you're trying to match (provided the university domains are similarly downcased, of course)
- You never need to loop, check a condition, and set a variable + `break` if that condition is true. The reason you don't need to that is because you have [`Enumerable#detect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to do it for you.
- This looks like a Rails project, so it'd probably be faster to either let the database check for you, or only load the column you need, instead of loading every single `University` record.

For instance, to let the DB check it, you can do this

```
match = University.where("? LIKE CONCAT('%', domain)", self.email).any?
errors.add(:email, "Sorry, no match found") unless match
```

Since you're not actually loading any records doing this, I'd imagine it's pretty fast (and case-insensitive, so no need for downcasing)

As for matching things in Ruby, [Nat's approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25829/14370) is the most straightforward one, I'd say.

I'd still do it a bit differently, though:

```
address = self.email.downcase

# only load the domain column values, since those are all we need here
match = University.pluck(:domain).detect { |domain| address.end_with?(domain) }

errors.add(:email, "Sorry, no match found") unless match
```

Of course, you should still check that the address is a valid email address in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

here's what I would do:

```
University.all.each do |uni|
  if email.end_with?(uni.domain)
    errors.add(:email, "Sorry, no match found")
    break
  end
end
```

it's not necessary to split the email address first because the `end_with?` method only considers at final substrings of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Build a regular expression from all your university domain, build it just once.
If you domains are **brunel.ac.uk bton.ac.uk cam.ac.uk** you
need to build the expression

```
/brunel\.ac\.uk$|bton\.ac\.uk$|cam\.ac\.uk$/
```

like so:

```
regular_expression = Regexp.new(
    University.all.map{|domain| Regexp.escape(domain)}.join("$|") + "$"
)
```

then match with this expression:

```
regular_expression.match(domain)
```

Comment: It's unlikely to matter, but i think it'd be more correct to escape the periods like `Regexp.new(University.all.join("$|").gsub(/\./,"\\.") + "$")`

Comment: thanks, good point.  I've adapted the code to use  Regexp.escape, that should solve the problem